# Lenovo e530 no wireless Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04

For some reason my wireless will not work on my Lenovo e530. I am dual booting ubuntu and windows 8 and my wireless works in windows. I saw online that I should run rfkill. I did that but only bluetooth shows up. There is no difference when I press the wireless fn key either, but it does block bluetooth (as it should). I'm really wanting to get into Ubuntu but this is holding me back. To clarify the wireless device does not show at all after running rfkill.

Comment: run iwconfig and paste the output

Comment: "eth0 no wireless extensions, lo no wireless extensions"

Comment: run  rfkill list all and post the results.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GS45f2tE

Comment: Please run: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and post the result.

Comment: okay I'm halfway there. The wireless now works but it only picks up 5GHz. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any clues here? dmesg | grep -e wl -e 80211

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install iw
iw reg get
sudo iw reg set NZ
iw reg get
sudo rmmod lib80211_crypt_tkip
```